# Multiply matrix with a vector row wise

Tags: r, matrix

I've got a logical matrix and I need to multiply each column by the sum of this column using apply. 
For example :

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1
> b <- colSums(a)
> b
[1] 3 2 1 3
```

And I want to get the following matrix :

```
 > a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    2    1    3
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    2    0    3
[4,]    3    0    0    3
```

I did it with for but since I need to apply my function to a huge dataset I need to code with apply. Thank you.

Comment: Does just `a * b` do what you want?

Comment: It does but it takes a long time to run. If I use the function apply of biganalystics it won't take long time, that's why I needed to use apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @akrun's answer, if you really do want to use `apply`:

```
apply(a,2,function(x)x*sum(x))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    2    1    3
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    3    2    0    3
#[4,]    3    0    0    3
```

`2` means you work on columns (i. e. the second dimension). So each operation is done on a vector corresponding to a column, hence the use of `sum` (which works on vector) instead of `colSums` (which works on a matrix).

Answer (score 3):

You can take the transpose (`t`) of the matrix 'a' and then multiply with the vector ('b'), take the transpose (`t`) of the output to get the desired result.

```
 t(t(a)*b)
```

Or we can make the lengths of the 'a' and 'b' same by replicating the elements of 'b'.  By doing `b[col(a)]`, we get each element of 'b' replicated by the index provided by the `col`.

```
 a*b[col(a)]
```

For better understanding

```
  col(a)
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  #[1,]    1    2    3    4
  #[2,]    1    2    3    4
  #[3,]    1    2    3    4
  #[4,]    1    2    3    4

 b[col(a)] #is a vector
 #[1] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3

 a*b[col(a)]
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    3    2    1    3
 #[2,]    0    0    0    0
 #[3,]    3    2    0    3
 #[4,]    3    0    0    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer akrun. I tried that but R cannot run that operation because I have a huge matrix (bigmemory)

Comment: @TaoufiqMouhcine  In that case, the `apply` would be more appropriate as the big matrix will take a toll on the memory.  I didn't read the part where you mentioned big data (sorry!)